# How to write a Connection String

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am trying to use VBA in Excel to query a SQL database and I was given the below code as the starting point which is awesome but I don't know the syntax for writing a connection string and so far have been unable to find it. Hoping you guys can help me.

```
Dim cn as new ADODB.Connection
Dim rs as new ADODB.Recordset

Cn.ConnectionString = “your connection string”
Cn.Open
Rs.Open “query like SELECT * FROM MYTABLE etc.”, cn
Range(“A1”).CopyFromRecordset rs

Rs.close
Cn.close
```

Comment: if you do some googling im sure you will find tons of examples

Comment: [www.connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) is a good place to start.  Something like this: `cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=databaseName;TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES"`

Comment: I have been googling for the last 2 weeks and had not yet found what I needed to make sense to my brain. However what Portland Runner provided is very useful Thank you sir. Now I just need to figure out why it is giving me a complie error: User-Defined type not defined error on the first line of Dim

Comment: Use the VBE's `Tools ► References` to include one of the ADO compiler reference libraries like *Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.5 Library*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code may help you (it's just something I had on hand close to what you're trying to do and not a rewrite of yours), but your connection string will vary based on your database. Go [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) for more information on syntax for the string itself. You are getting a compile error because you do not have the proper references. In the VBE, go to Tools and select References. Make sure ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library is checked.

```
 Private Sub GetFieldNames()

 Set con1 = New ADODB.Connection
 Set rs1 = New ADODB.Recordset
 Dim ProjectName As String
 Dim ConCat As String

 con1.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=SERVERADDRESS;Initial Catalog=DATABSE;IntegratedSecurity=SSPI"
 con1.Open

 With rs1
     .ActiveConnection = con1
     .Open "SELECT column_name,* From information_schema.columns Where table_name = 'Projects' ORDER by ordinal_position"
     Sheet1.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs1

     .Close

 End With


 con1.Close
 Set con1 = Nothing

 End Sub
```

Comment: I was able to modify the code and add the reference as you suggested to get much further in this process however I am getting a different issue now where it says invalid authorization Specification error when it tries to open the connection string.

Comment: This is probably to do with the `IntegratedSecurity=SSPI` part. You need to work out how you connect to your SQL Server database. Is it by windows authentication or SQL Server authentication? Then you need to alter your connection string accordingly. There is a lot of info around about connection strings. Ask a specific question and we may be able to help.

Comment: I was able to get it to work I had to add the Password to the connection string(it is SQL Server Authentication) I just did not think I needed that part as the connection file excel makes when you do it using the wizard does not have it in that file and I was using that file to help write the code.